# Advice for a table top rpg with rpg systems

Tags: mathematics, rpg

English isn't my first language so sorry in advanced for odd wording.

Idk if this is the right type of form but,I would like to make a game much Like D&D.
With that said basic attacks seem to work out just fine no matter lvl or stats I think that the numbers come out a fair.

```
mag= (100 + buffs + gear) = sum
res= (100 + res + buffs + gear) = sum
magic damage =(A.mag*mag.sum)/(res.sum)
```

This pushes out fairly low numbers that are then ran into a set of code that does the damage by number of its.

```
*1 for attacks that are 5 to 10 hits
*2 for 2 to 4 hits
*4 for single hit skills and spells. (had a problem that made single hits to weak for a time.)
*.5 for skills/spells that hit 11 to 15 times.
```

So here is where the problem comes in this is a Ip i made over years of thinking and putting things together. Spells are ranked from 1 to 5 however 5 is a insta win at the cost of the users life.

I do want to note as Dm I use my pc to run the above code. I would love to hear any form of tips or advice that might make things run a little better in the long run.

If we plug the numbers from the race above at level 1 those numbers being 40 magic and give the attacker a weapon buff of 20 and a attack buff of 10 it should come out to 130. Note that the magic attack will not be used in getting the sum of these buffs. Now lets make the defends gear a gear buff of 10 and a res buff of 15. the res stat is used in the code as shown below leading us to our sum of .155

```
attacker (100 + 20 + 10) =130
defender (100 + 30 + 10 + 15) = 155
```

These numbers would give us our sum. this is then plugged into another set of code as seen below

```
(Mag*attacker sum)/(defender sum)
```

so if we plug in the numbers it should look like this.

```
(40*130)/(155)= 33.54
```

This is then taken automatically by the system and * by the following numbers 2,4,.5 this displays the outcomes of the above number as the first hit in the combo.

```
(40*130)/(155)= 33.54 <this is then * by the number of hits a 5-10 hit>
(40*130)/(155)= 33.54*2 = 67 <*2-4>
(40*130)/(155)= 33.54*4 = 134 <single hit spells>
(40*130)/(155)= 33.54*.5 = 16 <*10 to 15>
```

So to explain the above numbers lets say I use a spell that cast 15 chances to hit in damage that spell would use the formula of 10 to 15 or .5 making each hit deal 16 damage if they all land that would be 240 damage taken. if unlucky however only 3 of those 15 could hit and you would still use the 16 as your base damage for said attack.

In theory this should be fine (i think) this makes some AoE's broken as a AoE without a chance to miss would deal massive damage every time. So maybe in the long run my question might really is their a way to make this more fair for pvp?

**In case asked**

Yes I am likely tying harder than I need to.

I can also Show what a a good player sheet and a broken player sheet look like if someone thinks it would help. I do hope that this is more clear than before or at most gives a better idea of what i'm tying to ask.

I have never made a game I have less than a year of html,c# and,c++ under my belt so i hope it kinda looks like it should work.

Thank you for all replies

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking or how the formulae you provided are applied. For example, where does "number of hits" come from? I'd recommend maybe splitting this into multiple questions, each with a clear, specific goal.

Comment: I think this might explain it better however I agree that I was likely to vast I should be working on one problem at a time rather than the over all picture. Thank you for bringing this to light.